# Server side validation in playframework 2.0 in a jquery pop up

Tags: jquery, playframework-2.0

I am using play framework 2.0.1. I have a form in a jquery pop up in which I have to validate in the server side and display the validation message WITHOUT CLOSING the pop up.

I've tried to use java script routes as given in the zen tasks example, but I think there is no example to make the ajax call from client side.

I could not find any other examples for using ajax in play framework 2.0.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On the client side**, you can call your own javascript function which will gather all your form inputs :

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@routes.MyController.myMethod()",
        data: { username: $("#myForm #username").val(), age: $("#myForm #age").val() },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("Success of call");
            //Do what you want here
            //For example close the jquery opened panel
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Failure of call");
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

**On the server side**, you will treat the incoming request as anyother (This is a scala example, adapt it for java) :

```
def connectWithFB = Action { implicit request =>
    Form(tuple("username" -> nonEmptyText, "age" -> nonEmptyText)).bindFromRequest.fold(
        errors =>  {
            BadRequest(toJson(Map("status" -> "0", "error" -> "Missing fields or wrong field")))
        },
        success => {
            Ok(toJson(Map("status" -> "1")))
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your immediate response.  Can you please explain how to call a java script method. since I am a very newbie to jquery..I'm having the following code.               @helper.form(action = routes.Drabble.submit, 'id -> "myForm") { <span>@inputText(drabbleForm("title"))</span>                    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="PUBLISH"/> }                                                                    and the pop up ic closing even after required field not entered. Please help.

Comment: You should consider splitting your questions in different StackOverflow threads. javascript, jQuery, Ajax, Play templates and Play controllers are very different subjects. If you don't know enough one of them ask a very specific question on SO.

Comment: Thanks kheraud for your response.

Comment: If it answers your question please mark the answer as the good one (the green check)

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap its so easy to do validation ,
as an example:

```
<div class="form-group" style="position:relative;left:20px;">
   <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2"><strong>  Genre</strong>
            </label>
     <input type="text" name="genre" required />


     </div>
```

all you have to do is saying that it´s required like that

```
<input type="text" name="genre" required />
```

Cheers